# CheckBox to select or deselect all the items of a column SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a SQL column of type bit (boolean), I can check or uncheck some items of my choice from a data grid, where those checkboxes are shown. Now I want to have a single checkbox to select or deselect all the checkboxes into the data grid. I've arrived at this code:

```
private void Chk_All_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {

    CORRENTE

    string q = @"UPDATE tabL
                     SET selection = (CASE 
                                        WHEN (SELECT selection FROM tabL ) = 0
                                        THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                      END)
                     WHERE ?????????????????????";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("All Items Checked");


  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
}
```

"WHERE idL=@CURRENT" is wrong

Here is another try but isn't working as well:

```
private void Chk_All_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    string q = @"UPDATE tabL
                     SET selection = 1";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("All Items Checked");


    string q2 = @"UPDATE tabL
                     SET selection = 0";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(q2, sqliteCon);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("All Items DeChecked");


  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: You never add the `@CURRENT` parameter to your SQL statement.

Comment: i don't need to know the exact position of the line @CURRENT because i have to check or uncheck all of them, setting them all to 0 or all to 1

Comment: I think you misunderstand. You [need to add a SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) to the command.

Comment: i know but know what parameters to add

Comment: only a checkbox to set all the column 'selection' of a table 'tabList' to 1 if checked and to 0 if unchecked,what isn't clear? sorry but i'm not understanding the problem

Comment: the checkbox i'm searching for is the implementation of an object chkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

378 views 0 solutions but i've found one by my own
the chkbox object have got two event handlers one for checked and one for deceked.

```
private void Chk_All_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    if (chk_All.IsChecked == true) { 
    string q = @"UPDATE tabList
                     SET selection = 1";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("All Items Checked");
    }


  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
}



  private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  sqliteCon.Open();
  if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    if (chk_All.IsChecked == false)
    {
      string q2 = @"UPDATE tabList
                     SET selection = 0";
      SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(q2, sqliteCon);
      cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("All Items DeChecked");
    }
  }
  sqliteCon.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code:**

```
private void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {         
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index == e.RowIndex)
            {
                row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value = 
                !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].EditedFormattedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to check or uncheck em all on a click of a single and separated checkbox born to do that(Chk_All)

Comment: datagrdiview is from windows form

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a brief explanation of how this solves the problem.

Comment: thank you,considering that DataGridView isn't from WPF